# Web calls between bridged docker containers

Tags: docker, networking

For the sake of argument, lets suppose I have 2 services running in 2 separate containers.  Lets name them service A and service B.  Service B hosts a web service and makes it visible to the outside world via -p 8080:8080.  The outside world has no problem calling this web service.  However, service A also needs to call the web service hosted by service B.  This is what I've tried:

**Create Bridge Network**

```
docker network create my-network
```

**Run containers connected to that network**

```
docker run --net=my-network service-a
docker run --net=my-network -p 8080:8080 service-b
```

**Check network participation**

```
docker network inspect my-network    BOTH SERVICES CONNECTED!!
```

**Outside the container**

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/someMethod     THIS WORKS!!!
```

**From service-a**

```
http://my-network:8080/someMethod    THIS DOES NOT WORK!!
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the IP of the host that docker is running on?  For example, lets say that it is 10.0.1.5.  From outside of docker AND from within the container for the other service (service-a), you can connect to service-b with

```
http://10.0.1.5:8080
```

Also, since you are using a user-defined bridge network, I believe you can use the name of the container you want to connect to if both containers are on the same interface.

```
http://service-b:8080
```

**Background:**

I may be wrong but by default when you use a bridge network, the external IP of your host machine is 'extended' to docker.  By using the -p option, you are binding the port of the docker container to the host.  The container will now be accessible at :

Answer (score 0):

Provided the above docker configuration, the following will make it work:

**create alias for service-b in docker run command**

```
docker run --net=my-network --network-alias service-b-hostname -p 8080:8080 service-b
```

**reference that service**

```
http://service-b-hostname:8080/someMethod
```